# how can i get instance of sales force cloud programmatically

Tags: salesforce

I want to get instance of sales force cloud programmatically. I was looking into partner api but there no such method exist that can provide cloud instance information. Also on the google not very much helpful information available related to salesforce api.

If you click on below mentioned url you can see the salesforce cloud instance with their status.

http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/

This information i want to access programmatically. I also want ot access

Number of Transactions 
Avg. Speed (seconds).

Comment: So you have an authenticated user and you want to know the connection url, like na17.salesforce.com?

Comment: In my app. i need to generate alarm based on status of cloud instance. Like if a particular sales force instance is down in that case i will raise a alrm. And to read the cloud instance status i need a api. But i have not found any useful sales force api that provides this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an oauth auth token you can use the User Info REST API:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo?oauth_token=$token

This will return the user's instance URL.

More info: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_userinfo_endpoint.htm